# Making a django blog: says database column is missing when 'sql' shows the column exists

Tags: django

here is the error in question:
[image: error screenshot]

I've run syncdb and restarted the server.

Answer (score 2):

The "sql" command shows what SQL would be run by syncdb, not what columns actually exist currently in the table; double-check the column existence in a DB tool.

syncdb won't add columns to existing tables, only create brand new ones. You'll want to look at a project like South http://south.aeracode.org/ to manage adding comlumns (or run the `alter table add column` manually.)

Comment: Thank you, that is good to know. But surely there must be a way to, when updating model attributes, update the database concurrently? 
(Also, exploring the database using shell shows that the model does indeed have a pub_date attribute: >>> p = Post(title='yo', pub_date=datetime.datetime.now(), content='hello california')
>>> p.pub_date
datetime.datetime(2010, 12, 3, 16, 33, 42, 165486))

Comment: Ian, that is exactly what south is good for. database migrations don't come with vanilla django. Also, your example doesn't "prove" that it exists in the database. The Post instance is just a regular python object in memory before you call .save() on it.

Comment: Unfortunately, Django does not come with such an updater, and their current advice is to use a 3rd party tool such as South.

Comment: Ah, well that is disappointing. I will install and use south!            Thanks a lot guys.